# MySQL 5.7 prepared statements updating the wrong timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, sql-update, prepared-statement

I'm having some issues with an update on table, when used with a prepared statement.
Seems like mysql is updateing a wrong column which was not even specifed in the update command.

prepare:

```
drop table test1;
create table test1(
  id int not null,
  show_from timestamp not null,
  updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
insert into test1(id, show_from, updated_at) values(1, '2018-01-11 12:10:11.19808', '2019-04-15 11:50:00.704748');
```

do this in one batch:

```
UPDATE test1 SET show_from='2018-04-15 11:50:00.704748' WHERE id=1;
SELECT * FROM test1;
```

returns:

```
1    2018-04-15 13:50:01    2019-04-15 13:50:01
```

as expected.

Now do this in one batch:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'UPDATE test1 SET updated_at=? WHERE id=?';
SET @s1='2019-02-11 12:12:11.19808';
SET @s2=1;
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @s1, @s2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
SELECT * FROM test1;
```

returns:

```
1    2019-04-15 12:54:27    2019-02-11 13:12:11
```

Why did mysql update the show_from column?

Comment: The first update should reset show from to '2018-04-15 11:50:00.704748' (and does when I test it) but your result is 2018-04-15 13:50:01 which makes me suspect the published table definition is incorrect OR you have A TRIGGER in play.

Comment: probably UTC? i'm GMT+2 here.

Comment: No triggers. just created the table for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column is declared timestamp, ***not null***:

```
show_from timestamp not null
```

In this mode, MySQL will update the column every time the row (any of its columns) is updated. [From the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp):

If the `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` system variable is disabled, the first `TIMESTAMP` column has both `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` if neither is specified explicitly.

The documentation suggests workarounds such as:

> - Define the column with a DEFAULT clause that specifies a constant default value.
> - Specify the NULL attribute. This also causes the column to permit NULL values, which means that you cannot assign the current timestamp
>     by setting the column to NULL.

I would actually recommend this:

> - Enable the `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` system variable.

Comment: Oh my god. This is horrible ... but thank you. this solves my problem.