# Field start_time is being updated automatically when updating end_time

Tags: mysql, laravel, timestamp

I'm using laravel 6 and mysql 5.7 for my project and I have put two columns `start_time` and `end_time` in my model and both are in `timestamp` type. In an action I create a record and initialize `start_time` value. In another action I update `end_time` column of that record.
Here is my code when creating the item:

```
DeviceUsage::create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'device_id' => $request->input('device_id'),
    'start_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
]);
```

And this is query's log:

```
'query' => 'insert into `device_usages` (`user_id`, `device_id`, `start_time`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
'bindings' => 
array (
  0 => 3,
  1 => '1',
  2 => '2019-12-11 10:33:51',
  3 => '2019-12-11 10:33:51',
  4 => '2019-12-11 10:33:51',
),
'time' => 0.68,
```

And database after create command:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+----------+
| id | device_id | start_time          | end_time |
+----+-----------+---------------------+----------+
|  1 |         2 | 2019-12-11 11:26:53 | NULL     |
+----+-----------+---------------------+----------+
```

Here is my update code:

```
$deviceUsage = DeviceUsage::where('device_id', $oldDeviceId)->where('user_id', $user->id)->whereNull('end_time')->first();
if (!empty($deviceUsage)) {
    $deviceUsage->update(['end_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
}
```

And update query log:

```
'query' => 'update `device_usages` set `end_time` = ?, `device_usages`.`updated_at` = ? where `id` = ?',
'bindings' => 
array (
  0 => '2019-12-11 10:33:51',
  1 => '2019-12-11 10:33:51',
  2 => 12,
),
'time' => 1.41,
```

And database after update command:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | device_id | start_time          | end_time            |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         2 | 2019-12-11 14:59:24 | 2019-12-11 11:29:24 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I have no idea why `start_time` is being updated to local time of `end_time` (my local time is UTC+3:30).

Comment: have you cheked the default for the field? is it set to "current timestamp on update"

Comment: Oh, yes it is. but why? My migration: `$table->timestamp('start_time'); $table->timestamp('end_time')->nullable();`

Comment: if it is set to "currect timestamp on update" so no matter if you assign value to it or not it will always set the current timestamp whenever there is any update

Comment: Thank you @BlackXero. Write your comment as answer so that I mark it as my answer.

Comment: Thank you for accepting it, I have wrote it as answer, :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687680/mysql-5-7-prepared-statements-updating-the-wrong-timestamp-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you cheked the default for the field? is it set to "current timestamp on update"

Comment: Additional article: https://ma.ttias.be/laravel-mysql-auto-adding-update-current_timestamp-timestamp-fields/